# 3 axis chart all combos

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "R" : [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1],
    "F" : [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2],
    "M" : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4]
})
```

I'm having no luck with creating something similar to the sample below in python. As you may notice it shows you all possible combinations of the dataframe above; note the three axis:

[image]

Anyone familiar with how to do this with seaborn, matplotlib,  etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is `sns.countplot` paired with `sns.FacetGrid`:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,6, size=(100,3)), columns=['R','F','M'])

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='R', col='F', )
g.map(sns.countplot, 'M', order=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

Output:

[image]